# How do I fix broken packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I have a problem with `apt`.

When I try to update or upgrade Ubuntu, I receive an error telling me that I have dependency problems, and I can't go on. I've tried to solve the problem with `apt-get install -f`, `aptitude install -f`, and using Synaptic, but I couldn't solve it.

When I try to run Synaptic, it tells me that I have broken packages, but if I try to delete them, it tells me that it will remove a lot of essential packages like `mount` and `hostname`. I think that it would be the end of my Ubuntu if I proceed.

Comment: It would be easier to track down your problem if you provide the error you get (the output from the terminal).

Comment: Synaptic>Edit>Fix Broken Packages

Comment: ...also...did you use sudo first? i.e. sudo apt-get install -f ...

Comment: this is my console output [link](http://pastebin.com/TcpWXCRB), sorry is in Spanish

Answer (score 0):

You could use synaptic package manager ( to get there via menue : system tools ---> system administration ).

Then log in with password. Then inside of synaptic make query for package which is broken. Remove it completely with right mouse-key and hook. Apply your choice.

When finish then make query again for same package-name. Install it with right mouse-key and hook. Apply your choice. Done.

(Sometimes it can happen that package-installation simply fails. Then it is somehow "broken".)

Hope this runs.

:)